# Why these syntactically identical functions produce different results?

Tags: javascript, return

```
function foo1() {
    return {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}

function foo2() {
    return
    {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}

console.log(foo1());
console.log(foo2());
```

Can I get an explanation why the two functions print out different results even though the code looks the same?

Comment: And also a [helpful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Automatic semicolon insertion**

Quoting [the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-rules-of-automatic-semicolon-insertion),

> When a `continue`, `break`, `return`, `throw`, or `yield` token is encountered and a *LineTerminator* is encountered before the next token, a semicolon is automatically inserted after the `continue`, `break`, `return`, `throw`, or `yield` token.

So the code will become like this

```
function foo2() {
    return;          // Note the `;` after `return`
    {
        bar: "hello"
    };
}
```

The `return` statement terminates and then there is an object after that, which is basically unreachable code. Since the `return` statement doesn't return anything explicitly, `undefined` will be returned.